# plot more than 2 PCAs in 2D in R

Tags: r, pca, data-visualization

I have done a PCA analysis where 7 PCAs explain about  80% of cumulative variation in the data. I would like to plot the scores for all 7 PCAs in R but not sure on how to achieve it. When I use biplot function, it plots scores for all PCAs (16 in total in my case), and the plot becomes rather messy. Rest by general plotting, I am only able to a make a 2D plot with PCA 1 and PCA 2. Is there a way I can plot only 7 PCAs in 2 dimension like how biplot does?
Thanks bunch in advance!

Comment: By "PCAs" do you mean *principal components* (PCs)?  Or are you indeed performing multiple Principal Components Analyses (PCAs) and wish to plot all their results simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the R function *biplot* does not provide a parameter to limit the number of loadings to be shown.

You can however easily draw the loadings yourself into the scatterplot with *lines* or *arrows*, e.g.

```
arrows(rep(0,7), rep(0,7), loadings[1,1:7], loadings[2,1:7])
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try pairwise plot on pairwise PC, i.e, one 2D plot to show PC1-PC2, one plot to show PC2-PC3, one plot to show PC1-PC3 etc..

This is used in R to show high dimensional data. For example `plot(iris)` will show

[image]